# Limiting the speed of an induction generator

Tags: generator, motor-controller, induction

A turbine (whose angular speed **must not** exceed \$\omega_{max}\$) is driving a 3-phase induction generator.

I envisage the generator's electrical output being monitored by a circuit that reacts to frequency \$f\$ approaching \$\frac{\omega_{max}}{2\pi}\$ by manipulating the generator's electrical load (and/or introducing power) in order to induce a "braking" EMF.

If power is introduced, it must only *resist* the turbine's mechanical drive—and **never** drive the turbine itself.  Therefore, because the fluid flow that actually drives the turbine is erratic (and could cease at any moment), any applied power must instantly respond to fluctuations in the mechanical drive.

Could this approach work?  Does it already exist in reality and/or have a name?  Are there any limits to the braking torque that a given such system could deliver?  How might the control circuit look?

Comment: Many use flywheels to low pass filter the mechanical energy

Answer (score 1):

You can control the turbine by controlling the electrical load on the generator if you have a system that can receive power from the turbine generator and deliver power to the load at any required rate. That type of system is used for existing wind-turbine induction generators. With a grid-tie inverter, there is no limit to the level of power that can be delivered to the grid. With an off-grid system, a dump load dissipates power in excess of the power required for loads.

To deliver power to a grid, a grid-tie inverter is required. For isolated loads, the induction-generator output can be rectified and furnished to the load through a DC regulator or converter. AC power could be delivered through an inverter that is not grid-tie capable.

Limits to the braking torque available would be mostly related to induction-generator, controller and dump load sizing. For something like a wind turbine, auxiliary mechanical systems may be required to "feather the prop" or bypass fluid flow.

Comment: Thank you for this answer (FYI this system is off-grid).  Do you mean to say that (given appropriate sizing) one should be able to achieve *any* amount of braking force (including that required to bring the turbine from any speed/torque to a complete stop?) purely by applying a sufficiently large electrical load on the generator?  (Surely a complete stop would require that the stator field becomes stationary, and if so that the rotor has no induced current?  Or is it merely possible, at least in theory, to reduce angular speed to something close to nil but not actually zero?)

Comment: You can not bring the turbine to a stop or even close to a complete stop. You should be able to prevent the turbine from reaching an excessively high speed, but you may need to take other measures to protect the turbine mechanically during extreme conditions. If you need to stop the turbine, that will need to be done mechanically.

Comment: Is there something you can point me toward to help me understand this a little better?  If electrical load produces a braking torque, then why does that break down at low speeds?

Comment: At zero speed, it is difficult for the generator to produce any torque. For one thing, it would need to draw current from batteries to for magnetization. The controller would need to be pretty sophisticated to accurately determine what voltage and frequency to apply. I have not studied induction generator control in depth. Ned Mohan "Power Electronics: Converters, Applications, and Design" is likely one place to look.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generator. So your torque is **always** a braking torque. You have to ensure your mechanical frequency is **always** above the electrical one.

The usual way to do this is to maintain a constant slip. This can be done by measuring the electrical power coming from the generator and adjusting either

- the stator frequency. The downside is you have a variable electrical frequency. Not feasible for a machine on the grid. You need an AC-AC converter.
- the rotor frequency. The downside is you need a machine with rotor windings and slip rings. The supply converter for the rotor winding may be much smaller than an AC-AC converter on the stator windings had to be.